# ImportError: cannot import name 'registry' from 'pandas.core.dtypes.base'

Tags: python, pandas

I just did a conda install of a few packages to follow a tutorial, and now I can't even import pandas.

I installed these:

```
fake-factory==0.7.2
Faker==0.7.3
pytz==2016.7
tzlocal==1.3.0
```

And now I get this:

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ariel\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ariel\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.core.arrays.integer import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ariel\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .base import (ExtensionArray,    # noqa
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ariel\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\base.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pandas.core import ops
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ariel\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pandas.core.construction import extract_array
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ariel\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.base import ExtensionDtype, registry
ImportError: cannot import name 'registry' from 'pandas.core.dtypes.base' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ariel\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\base.py)
```

I tried doing a conda update pandas, but to no avail.

I also just installed luigi, not quite sure when it broke as I installed all the additional packages in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Updated version of `pandas` package using `pip3`
try this in `python3`

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating pandas package in Anaconda:

```
conda install pandas=1.1.4
```

If no luck, try updating all packages:

```
conda update --all
```

Worked in my case.